# How long do firebase credentials remain on web client

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

How long do the **firebase credentials** last in the **web client**, I am making a web application that is planning to stay offline for months and when they get back online it will be updated. What I need to know is how long they last, can the time be increased?.

I have looked in the firebase documentation but I have not been able to find the desired information

I mean these credentials https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZqH5.png

Comment: BY credentials do you mean how long the user stays logged in without opening the app for years?

Comment: Yes, I mean the credentials that allow you to enter without having to enter email or password again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is from the documentation right [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence):

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  .then(function() {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

The word "**Local**" indicates that indicates that the state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state.

So the user stay logged in forever unless the browser is re-installed or data is cleared.
There are other two mode alongside 'Local' - 'Session' and 'Null'. You can read about them in the link provided above.

By the way, it's "LOCAL" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it appears the behavior of firebase credentials [is customizable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).